# Cannot unpack .tgz mongodb distribution on OSX

Tags: mongodb, macos, tar, gzip

I grab the tgz file via

```
curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz
```

yes I want mongodb version 2.6.12... :(

and I try to unzip it using:

```
tar -xvzf mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz
```

but I get:

```
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

anybody know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file didn't download property, so even though it was a .tgz file on the filesystem it was incomplete or corrupted. To get a proper download I had to drop the ssl

before:

```
curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz
```

after:

```
curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz
```

then unpacking with tar worked. √

Comment: For the 3.4.2 version there's a bit of a difference from the answer. I've changed: `curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx-ssl/mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.4.2.tgz` for `curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.4.2.tgz`